# $x''-2x'+x=e^{t}+e^{2t}\sin(t)$ differential equation

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

How to solve $x''-2x'+x=e^{t}+e^{2t}\sin(t)$ differential equation?

I solved the equation=0 and I got solution 1, a double solution.

What's the form of the particular solution ? I wrote $xp=e^{t}A+t^{2}e^{2t}(C\cos t+D\sin t)$ Is this correct?

Comment: $2+i$ is not a root of the characteristic equation, so I fail to see the point of having that $t^2$ in the latter term. The former term on the other hand needs that $t^2$ because $r=1$ was a double root.

Comment: So xp would be $t^{2}e^{t}A + e^{2t}(Ccost+Dsint)$ ?

Comment: See [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/849542/11619) or [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2317301/11619).

Comment: I think it should be $e^{t}A+e^{2t}(Ccost+Dsint)$

Comment: Use Laplace transform if you are allowed.

Answer (score 1):

$$x''-2x'+x=e^{t}+e^{2t}\sin(t)$$
Is equivalent to the following DE:
$$(xe^{-t})''=1+e^t \sin t$$
Integrate twice.